# cant export OBJ's with images

Tags: texturing, export

working in Blender 2.93.5

I baked my materials to a texture:
[image]

Which looks like this in the material graph:
[image]

I go to export the OBJ with materials:
[image]

But no textures seem to be written:

[image]

And importing the object results in no textures. How do I export an OBJ with textures?

Comment: Use a Principled node and put your texture in the Base Color. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html

Answer (score 0):

As scurest said, you need to use a Pincipled node